# Compare the 2 csv files and load the difference in target excel in 1 excel different sheets I need output

Tags: talend

Edit schema: I have two csv files in the source. First name, last name, gender, phone number, and email are the columns that are the same in two CSV files that I have (the index is the primary key). However, the data differs somewhat. I need to compare the two files and load the differences into the target Excel sheet. The output I require is something like source difference 1 sheet and target difference 2 sheet. Source is not in the target 3 sheet; it is not in the target sheet. One Excel file contains all of the sheets.

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

I tried by using tmap  and in tmap I write logic and perform inner join.